# Windows Forms wait 5 seconds before displaying a message

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, sleep

I want to make the user wait for 5 seconds before the user can do something but I'm having trouble as I don't want to do `Thread.Sleep(5000);` as I want the form to be loaded and the functionality to be be viewable but I don't want to allow the user to do anything for those 5 seconds (well they can attempt to click buttons but nothing should happen).

What I did to make this work (my code is slightly different due to properties) thanks to the answerer:

```
var t = Task.Delay(1000) //1 second/1000 ms
t.Wait();
```

Comment: sounds like you're trying to do something that we/users would not like  :P

Comment: @Jason, I know right :D! Luckily this program will never be used, it's just an exercise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can always disable all form and after 5 seconds enable it...

(example using .net framework 4.5)

```
//Your window Constructor
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor; 
    this.Enabled = false;
    WaitSomeTime();

    //load stuff
    .....
}

public async void WaitSomeTime()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    this.Enabled = true;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default; 
}
```

Comment: What if it is not framework 4.5 .Then what will be the approach?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a splash screen that is dismissed after 5 seconds.

There are quite a few resources on the web that show approaches to creating a WinForms splash screen (which is not as easy as it might sound), including

http://mrbool.com/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-in-csharp/26598

You can have a timer simply inform the splash screen after 5 seconds that loading is complete.

Comment: That looks like a lot of code at a quick glance. The other person that posted seems to have a more suited solution but thanks for your post :)!

Comment: Yeah the other solution is very elegant.  Was much harder to do before async/await was introduced.

Comment: It is indeed but it turns out it doesn't work, I can still click buttons *cries*

Comment: You should edit the accepted answer to show what additional steps you needed to make it work.  That way, the answer is more useful to the next person with the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

have your constructor call a background worker and on the work completed event load your main form.